# concatenation of the constants in systemverilog

Tags: concatenation, system-verilog

I wrote a code like below for concatenation but it's showing an error:

```
module main ;  
 bit [4:0] a;  
 reg b,c,d;  
 initial  
 begin  
    b = 0;  
    c = 1;  
    d = 1;  
    a = {b,c,0,0,d};  
    {b,c,d} = 3'b111;  
    $display(" a %b b %b c %b d %b ",a,b,c,d);  
 end  
endmodule
```

Here the error is showing that `constants cannot be concatenated`.

It's not able to concatenate the zeros and ones here. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: what's this line says - {b,c,d} = 3'b111 ?

Comment: `    {b,c,d} = 3'b111;  `  this line means b,c & d will be assigned as 1'b1, 1'b1 & 1'b1 respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current code is concatenating 32 bit (or integer) width 0's. What you actually want is:

```
a = {b, c, 1'b0, 1'b0, d};
```

NB: Putting this through cadence tools I get:

```
file: main.sv
    a = {b,c,0,0,d};  
             |
ncvlog: *E,NONOWD (main.sv,11|13): Illegal use of a constant without an explicit width specification [4.1.14(IEEE)].
    a = {b,c,0,0,d};  
               |
ncvlog: *E,NONOWD (main.sv,11|15): Illegal use of a constant without an explicit width specification [4.1.14(IEEE)].
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see [IEEE 1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), in 11.4.12 Concatenation operators

> Unsized constant numbers shall not be allowed in concatenations. This
>   is because the size of each operand in the concatenation is needed to
>   calculate the complete size of the concatenation.

So it it an illegal usage. You must explicitly specify the bit size of constant numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says that constants cannot be concatenated, here you are trying to concatenate constant values which is illegal. Explicitly mentioning the bit sizes of each value will solve your issue. Below is the code:

```
module concat;
  bit [4:0] a;
  reg b,c,d;
  initial
  begin
    b=1'b0;
    c=1'b1;
    d=1'b1;
    a={b,c,1'b0,1'b0,d};
    {b,c,d}=3'b111;
    $display("a: %b, b: %b, c: %b, d: %b",a,b,c,d);
  end
endmodule
```